# Does Z gate swap complex amplitudes of $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-gate, textbook-and-exercises

I am reading *Quantum Computing 1st Edition* By Parag Lala, [this book](https://www.mheducation.com/highered/product/quantum-computing-lala/9781260123111.html) says

[image]

It seemed that the Z gate swapped the complex amplitudes $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Can Z gate implement that, or are there any errata? Because

$$
\begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ -\beta \end{pmatrix} = \alpha\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} - \beta\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \neq \alpha\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + \beta\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \alpha|1\rangle + \beta|0\rangle
$$

And, is it true that Z Gate merely add $\pi$ to the relative phase $\phi$ of a superposition $|q\rangle$?

$$
|q\rangle = \alpha|0\rangle + e^{i\phi}\beta|1\rangle
$$
$$
Z|q\rangle = \alpha|0\rangle + e^{i(\phi+\pi)}\beta|1\rangle
$$

Comment: that's probably just a typo. The $Z$ gate only changes the sign of the amplitude of $|1\rangle$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong for sure.

And according to the book reviews on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07M7Y6T7F), this book is "unreliable",
"riddled with errors", and "someone studying for the first time will get confused"